# C# 4: Dynamic and Nullable<>

Tags: c#, dynamic, nullable

So I've got some code that passes around this anonymous object between methods:

```
var promo = new
{
    Text = promo.Value,
    StartDate = (startDate == null) ?
        new Nullable<DateTime>() : 
        new Nullable<DateTime>(DateTime.Parse(startDate.Value)),
    EndDate = (endDate == null) ?
        new Nullable<DateTime>() : 
        new Nullable<DateTime>(DateTime.Parse(endDate.Value))
};
```

Methods that receive this anonymous object type declare its type as `dynamic`:

```
private static bool IsPromoActive(dynamic promo)
{
    return /* check StartDate, EndDate */
}
```

At run-time, however, if `StartDate` or `EndDate` are set to `new Nullable<DateTime>(DateTime.Parse(...))`, a method that receives this `dynamic` object (named `promo`) performs this:

```
if (promo.StartDate.HasValue && promo.StartDate > DateTime.Today ||
    promo.EndDate.HasValue && promo.EndDate < DateTime.Today)
{
    return;
}
```

It throws an exception:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
'System.DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'HasValue'
```

What's going on here? What don't I understand about `Nullable` types and the `dynamic` keyword?

This code worked fine before I changed I removed the `struct` that previously stored `Text`, `StartDate`, and `EndDate` and replaced it with an anonymous type and passed it around as `dynamic`.

Comment: You have `promo.StartDate.HasValue`, but but at the same time you're using `promo.StartDate` as if it were the value.  The inconsistency appears to be a bug: use `promo.StartDate.HasValue` and `promo.StartDate.Value` or promo.StartDate == null` and `promo.StartDate`.  (I don't know which to use; I don't have .NET 4.0 available to test.)  Or ... there could be implicit casting going on, but I don't know if that's handled by `dynamic` very well.

Comment: Don't use that ugly `Nullable<T>` syntax; use `T?` instead :).

Comment: Interesting discovery, while without dynamic types, you'd have to use HasValue and Value. But as the runtime boxing strips the nullable info and leaves just the boxed value or null, you can't use these properties. So then, don't use HasValue at all, compare the object with null instead.

Answer (score 68):

Great question. Two facts that you probably don't know:

1. Dynamic behind the scenes is just object.  That is, a "dynamic" variable is an "object" variable with a hint to the compiler that says "generate dynamic operations on this variable when it is used."
2. There is no such thing as a boxed nullable. When you box an int? to object you get either a null object reference or a boxed int. The nullable wrapper around the int is thrown away.

Now it should be clear what is going on here. If promo is dynamic then promo.StartDate is dynamic. Which means that at runtime, it is object. Which means that if it is of value type, it is boxed. Which means that if it was nullable, it is now either a null reference or a boxed non-nullable value. Either way, that thing doesn't have a HasValue property. If you want to know whether it was in its value type form a nullable value type set to null, then check whether promo.StartDate is null or not.

Comment: So you're saying the runtime treats `Nullable<T>` special when dealing with `dynamic`?

Comment: @strager: No, that's not at all what I'm saying. The runtime knows *nothing* about "dynamic". "dynamic" exists only at compile time. *The runtime treats Nullable<T> as special when executing a boxing instruction.*

Comment: Would it make sense for the C# runtime binder to treat "HasValue" method calls specially when applied to a null reference to avoid this situation?

Comment: @kvb: No, that doesn't make sense because the suggestion does not avoid the stated situation at all. *The reference isn't null.* The error reported is that a boxed DateTime does not have a member called HasValue, not that someone is calling HasValue on a null reference.

Comment: Good point - you could try to patch that up as well by having "HasValue" return true when the argument is a boxed instance of a value type, but perhaps it's better not to go down that (increasingly complicated) road...

Comment: @kvb That's an interesting idea.  You actually wouldn't need to monkey with the runtime, just add to the BCL.  Add a propery on System.ValueType: `public bool HasValue { return true; }`.  What complications would that cause?