# Anomaly when using 'var' and 'dynamic'

Tags: c#, dynamic, compiler-construction

I've run into a bit on an Anomaly where for the first time ever, using the `var` keyword bit me.

Take this very simple method

```
public static Int32? GetNullableInt32(Int32 num)
{
    return new Nullable<Int32>(num);
}
```

Now we can call this method with a `dynamic` parameter and everything will work as expected.

```
public static void WorksAsAdvertised()
{
    dynamic thisIsAnInt32 = 42;

    //Explicitly defined type (no problems)
    Int32? shouldBeNullableInt32 = GetNullableInt32(thisIsAnInt32);

    Console.Write(shouldBeNullableInt32.HasValue);
}
```

However, by declaring `shouldBeNullableInt32` using implicit typing, the results are far from what *I* would expect.

```
public static void BlowsUpAtRuntime()
{
    dynamic thisIsAnInt32 = 42;

    //Now I'm a dynamic{int}... WTF!!!
    var shouldBeNullableInt32 = GetNullableInt32(thisIsAnInt32);

    //Throws a RuntimeBinderException
    Console.Write(shouldBeNullableInt32.HasValue);
}
```

Instead of being a `Nullable<Int32>` the return value get's treated as a dynamic type. And even then, the underlying `Nullable<T>` is not preserved. Since `System.Int32` has no property named `HasValue`, a `RuntimeBinderException` is thrown.

I would be **VERY** curious to hear from someone who can actually explain what is happening (not just guess).

### Two Questions

1. Why does `shouldBeNullableInt32` get **implicitly typed as a dynamic** when the return type of `GetNullableInt32` clearly returns a `Nullable<Int32>`?
2. Why is the underlying `Nullable<Int32>` not preserved? Why a `dynamic{int}` instead? *(**Answered here**: [C# 4: Dynamic and Nullable<>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728752/c-4-dynamic-and-nullable))*

---

### UPDATE

Both [Rick Sladkey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439637/anomaly-when-using-var-and-dynamic/7439891#7439891) and [Eric Lippert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439637/anomaly-when-using-var-and-dynamic/7440929#7440929) are equally valid. Please read them both :)

Comment: Also if you change `dynamic thisIsAnInt32 = 42;` to `int thisInAnInt32 = 42` the problem goes away as well.

Comment: Possibly related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728752/c-4-dynamic-and-nullable.  At least it addresses why the underlying Nullable<Int32> is not preserved.

Comment: @shf301 - Right. I didn't include that one in the example above because I felt it was a given. Removing the dynamic keyword makes everything very explicit. What I really want to know is why using dynamic as a parameter to a method causes the compiler to override what seems like should be a **no brainer**. However, I know very little about compiler theory and what seems basic to me may indeed be a very complicated problem.

Comment: Upon seeing the IL for the code, the return type of the method is changed to valueType than int32? type. So when your explicitly specifying the holding type i.e shouldBeNullableInt32 and since int32 is a descendent of valuetype. Hence things works out well. But when you say var, things are not explicit here. Return type will be still valuetype i guess. But surprising for me is, if you do GetType on it, u get int32 n not valuetype. But hey hasvalue on var item shud give u exceptions right?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> 1. Why does `shouldBeNullableInt32` get **implicitly typed as a dynamic** when the return type of `GetNullableInt32` clearly returns a `Nullable<Int32>`?

This is because while it is apparent to us that `GetNullableInt32` is the method that is going to be called, because of [**dynamic binding**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/ff628440), the actual method that *does* get called is deferred until run-time because it is being called with a dynamic parameter.  There might be another overload of `GetNullableInt32` that matches better the run-time value of `thisIsAnInt32`.  That alternate method, which cannot be known until run-time, **might return some other type than `Int32?`**!

As a result, the compiler, due to **dynamic binding** instead of static binding, cannot assume what the return type of the expression is at compile time and so the expression returns type **dynamic**.  This can be seen by hovering over `var`.

You appear to have already come to a satisfactory explanation for your second question here:

- [C# 4: Dynamic and Nullable<>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728752/c-4-dynamic-and-nullable)

Comment: I hadn't actually thought of that, but it certainly makes perfect sense.

Comment: It hurt my head to work the logic out, but it does make sense.

Answer (score 18):

Rick's answer is good, but just to summarize, you are running into the consequences of two basic design principles of the feature:

1. **if you ask for dynamic binding then you get dynamic binding**.
2. **dynamic is just object wearing a funny hat**.

The first issue you identify is a consequence of the first design principle. You asked for analysis of the call to be deferred until runtime. The compiler did so. That includes deferring *everything* about the call until runtime, including overload resolution and determining the return type. The fact that the compiler has enough information to make a guess about what you meant is irrelevant.

And if the compiler did make a guess about what you meant, then right now you'd be asking a different question, namely, "I made a tiny change to the set of methods available and suddenly the compiler changed its deduction of the type to dynamic, why?" It is very confusing to users when the compiler's behaviour is unpredictable.

(All that said, there are a small number of situations in which the compiler will tell you that dynamic code is wrong. There are situations where we know that a dynamic binding will *always* fail at runtime, and we can tell you about them at compile time rather than waiting for your test case to fail.)

The second issue you identify is a consequence of the second design principle. Because dynamic is just object wearing a funny hat, and because nullables box to either a null reference or a boxed non-nullable value type, there is no such thing as a "dynamic nullable".

Comment: I really wish I could mark two answers as accepted. Or merge them, and give you both the credit. And although I am a huge Lippert fan boy, I decided to mark @Rick's answer as accepted since his was first. Not that you probably care, but you know...