# Why does compiler infer var to be dynamic instead of concrete type?

Tags: c#

Given this short example program:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Test("hello world"));
    }

    private static int Test(dynamic value)
    {
        var chars = Chars(value.ToString());
        return chars.Count();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<char> Chars(string str)
    {
        return str.Distinct();
    }
```

When run, it will produce an exception similar to:

`Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ''object' does not contain a definition for 'Count''`

Meaning compiler chose `dynamic` as a preferred type of `chars` variable.

Is there any reason for it not to choose `IEnumerable<char>` as a concrete type, considering dynamic is not returned from `Chars` method? Just changing the type manually to `IEnumerable<char>` solves the issue, but I'm wondering why is `dynamic` a default value in this case?

**Edit**

I've probably used example which was more complex than necessary. It seems that the question asked here:

[Anomaly when using 'var' and 'dynamic'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439637/anomaly-when-using-var-and-dynamic)

Provides more concise example and some insights as to why it works the way it does.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2012/11/05/dynamic-contagion-part-one/

Describes how compiler handles dynamics.

Comment: I thought it was to do with `value` being `dynamic`, changing that to `string` resolves the issue without modifying `Chars`. I don't know _why_ though and would also be interested to know.

Comment: With a `dynamic` argument, overloads are resolved at runtime. Therefore, it declines to guess at compile time what method is actually being called when you call `Chars()`.

Comment: What happens when you leave `.ToString()` out?

Comment: The compiler does not know anything about ToString().  You might as well use ToFoo() and it will still compile.  So everything gets dynamically bound, even the Chars() call.  But Count() is an extension method, they won't be found by the DLR.  Simplest workaround is to help the compiler get it right with `(string)value.ToString()`.

Comment: @HenkHolterman It will fail with the same exception.

Comment: @HansPassant I think that's the missing piece here, I was not aware that Chars() is dynamically bound.

Comment: "... with the same exception" is what I expected. Shows that the arg to Chars() is dynamic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `dynamic`, all method calls are resolved at runtime. Therefore, it declines to guess at compile time what method is actually being called when you call `Chars()`, `Count()`, or even `ToString()`. It could be anything, returning anything. This is often called "dynamic contagion".

For all the compiler knows, somtimes `value.ToString()` will return `MyRandomPOCOClass`, and at runtime it'll be able to dig up some overload like `Tuple<int,String> Chars(MyRandomPOCOClass x)`. Maybe next time `value.ToString()` will return `int`. All bets are off. `dynamic` turns C# into a scripting language.

Here's an example of dynamic runtime overload behavior ([here's a fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kuuGQM)):

```
public static void Main()
{
    dynamic x = "foo";

    Test(x);

    x = 34;

    Test(x);
}

public static void Test(string s)
{
    Console.WriteLine("String " + s);
}
public static void Test(int n)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Int " + n);
}
```

Output:

```
String foo
Int 34
```

Comment: Also, at run time, the likelihood is that value.Tostring() will indeed be resolved to string.ToString() in this case, which has a logical implementation of "return this", since https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tc6ws5s(v=vs.110).aspx says... "this method simply returns the current string unchanged", 

Net effect, dynamic in = dynamic out.

Comment: Thanks, first paragraph explains the issue quite well, and it makes sense why it works like it does.

Answer (score 2):

With  `dynamic value`, how is the compiler to know what `value.ToString()` returns?

It has the same name as our familiar C# method, but it's different.

Comment: Shouldn´t this throw compiler-error as `Chars(dynamic)` doesn´t exist? I tried it, it doesn´t produce that error, making me wonder why.

Comment: @HimBromBeere If you want the compiler to tell you if a method does or doesn't exist, or if there is a problem with one of the types of your values, then don't turn the compiler off and tell it to not even try checking the types of any of the involved expressions by using `dynamic`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere It won't try to resolve the overload at compile time. At runtime, if the argument is `int`, it'll look for `Chars(int)`.

Comment: The whole point of `dynamic` is that it can serve as a stand-in for any value. `Chars(whatever)` is fine; at runtime a conversion will be attempted to `whatever`. The method itself must still exist (you can't call `Bars`).

Comment: @HimBromBeere Here's an example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/kuuGQM

Answer (score 0):

Because the parameter passed to Test() is dynamic, and that parameter is passed to Chars(). Dynamic essentially defers type checking to the runtime for any statements that involve dynamic types, and that is "viral", in the sense that any statement involving a dynamic variable can only yield a dynamic variable.

Answer (score 0):

> When you use str.Distinct(), it returns a object of type 
>       [System.Linq.Enumerable DistinctIterator](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,856287389e9cace3) of char type to your chars variable under `IEnumerable<char>`. 
>   That does not have a Count method itself. It is an iterator internally returning value one by one. 
>   Cast it to `IEnumerable<char>` to get the count. 
>   You can loop over the IEnumerable and print the values (for loop below works fine because it is an iterator) but the underlying returned value from the set does not have Count method, unless variable of type iterator is cast to `IEnumerable<char>`. 
>   Otherwise, you can use str.Distinct().ToList() and that will work fine without casting.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Test("hello world"));
}

private static int Test(dynamic value)
{
    var chars = Chars(value.ToString());
    //foreach (var c in chars)
    //        Console.WriteLine(c);
    return ((IEnumerable<char>)chars).Count();
}

private static IEnumerable<char> Chars(string str)
{
    return str.Distinct();
}
```