# Nullable DateTime error in Razor Template

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

#### Update

So it looks like this is replicateable in .NET 4.7.2 as well:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/NI8H1n

---

#### Original

I have been having an issue with a `DateTime?` in a razor template in a netcoreapp3.1. The template is being run through:

```
Engine.Razor.RunCompile("templateName", "templateKey" model: model);
```

The model being passed consists of the property:

```
public DateTime? IssueDate { get; set; }
```

The razor line that is throwing a null ref error inside the template is:

```
<td>Issue date: @(result.IssueDate.HasValue ? result.IssueDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : "")</td>
```

The error:

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference
```

---

So after some debugging, I found that if I change the problematic line in the template to:

```
<td>Issue date: @(result.IssueDate != null? result.IssueDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : "")</td>
```

Then we are good to go.

So the question I have is why doesn't the initial line work?

Comment: A bug, I'm guessing.  Consider `string s = null; var l = s.Length;`.  Since `s` is null, the call get the length will throw.  Now consider `bool? b = null; if (b.HasValue) {/*code*/}`. In the second case, the `null`-ness of `Nullable<T>` isn't the same as the `null`-ness of string.  A `bool?` has three possible values, `true`, `false` and `null`.  All of them are full on values of the type.  For reference types, `null` isn't a _value_ for the type, it's a possible value for a variable of that type.  My guess is that that subtlety was lost on the MSFT Razor dev who coded up the code for this.

Comment: C# dynamic (RuntimeBinder) doesn't like nullable types: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728752/c-sharp-4-dynamic-and-nullable and webpages generator makes heavy use of it, undercovers. Try to specify @model to avoid dynamic implicit usage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-5.0#model

Comment: The problem is very simple to resolve: define a default value in property, like `public DateTime? IssueDate { get; set; } = default(DateTime)`, about this topic, see at [C#, EF Core and Scaffold-DbContext, How to not passing null for a default valued column in the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68846270/c-ef-core-and-scaffold-dbcontext-how-to-not-passing-null-for-a-default-valued/68846366#68846366)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your view - copied here below from your Fiddle - does not contain a `@model` declaration, the type `dynamic` is being used for the viewmodel.

```
@(Model.SomeDate.HasValue ? Model.SomeDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : "No Value")
```

Once compiled, the above statement looks like below - notice the use of `dynamic`.

```
public override async Task ExecuteAsync()
{
    this.Write((((dynamic)base.Model).SomeDate.HasValue) 
        ? ((dynamic)base.Model).SomeDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") 
        : "No Value"
        );
}
```

Consider the information from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/reference-types#the-dynamic-type) about `dynamic`

> 1. Variables of type dynamic are compiled into variables of type object. Therefore, type dynamic exists only at compile time, not at
>    run time.
> 2. any **non-null** expression can be converted to the dynamic type

This makes that the type `dynamic` must evaluate its operations and data types at runtime.

---

```
public class SampleViewModel
{
    public DateTime? SomeDate {get;set;}
}
```

Given your model here above, where `SomeDate` is of type `Nullable<DateTime>`.

When that `SomeDate` property would have a value `null`, you get the `Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference` exception, since the code tries to access `.HasValue` on a `null`, instead on something that could have been converted to a `dynamic` (bullet point 2).

When that `SomeDate` would have a `DateTime.Now` value as shown in your Fiddle, the dynamic runtime binding concludes that `SomeDate` must be of type `System.DateTime` because `DateTime.Now` is not nullable and only a non-null expression can be converted to the `dynamic` type (bullet point 2).
Therefore you get the `'System.DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'HasValue'` exception, since a `DateTime` does not contain a `HasValue` property.

---

One way to make the `HasValue` check work, is by including the model declaration in the view, as it avoids having to use the type `dynamic` - see [updated Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ffzqip).

```
@model HelloWorldMvcApp.SampleViewModel
@(Model.SomeDate.HasValue ? Model.SomeDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : "No Value")
```