# C#, EF Core and Scaffold-DbContext, How to not passing null for a default valued column in the database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have created my domain using the below command and it works fine

```
Scaffold-DbContext -Connection name=MyConnectionStringName -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Force -Project My.Domain -StartupProject My.Api
```

I am migrating some code from a manual process of creating the domains, the original didn't have the **AuditApp** column defined which is defaulted in the database to the `App=MyApi` in the connection string. Here is the default constraint defined in the database:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PriceGroups] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_PriceGroups_AuditApp]  DEFAULT (rtrim(isnull(app_name(),''))) FOR [AuditApp]
```

Now that I have this column in the scaffold output I get this error when I try and add an object

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'AuditApp'
```

Is there a way for me to bypass this so that it doesn't pass it? or am I going to have to do a manual domain approach :/ ?

```
...
public string AuditApp { get; set; }
...
```

I will be wanting to run the scaffold tool often so need a solution that does not mean I have to change the auto generated code.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to [treat it as a read-only property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564772/ef-code-first-readonly-column).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, to meet your requirements quickly and guarantees to not break your application with this error, at property `AuditApp`, try add a default value, like this:

```
...
public string AuditApp { get; set; } = string.Empty;
...
```

Comment: So it looks like it is not possible if I want to keep generating a scaffold after each change. If my database didn't have default values then i would be ok. So in short once ive created the scaffold I have to maintain it manually and just add defaults like Antonio has said. not really what I wanted to hear but cheers.